# Несколько order by в MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Всем доброго времени суток!

Можно ли в sql-запросе использовать несколько "order by" ?

Мне необходимо взять только последние записи (по совпадению company_id и quest_id)и отсортировать их по убыванию даты и времени.

Пробовал :

1. `order by Field(date_time desc limit 1 , TIME_TO_SEC(date_time))` - не помогает
2. `order by date_time desc limit 1 , TIME_TO_SEC(date_time) и order by date_time desc limit 1 and TIME_TO_SEC(date_time)` - -тоже не хочет работать.

P.S. Вот,собственно,запрос, который у меня есть:

```
"SELECT purpose,date_time,objection,company_id,quest_id FROM `call` WHERE quest_id ='".$set_of_call['quest_id']."' and  company_id='".$set_of_call['company_id']."' order by date_time desc limit 1"
```

Он выбирает из таблицы call только последние записи ,а вот как отсортировать результат...?

Answer (score 4):

Вы не совсем корректно используете LIMIT. Вот так выглядит запрос в общем случае.

```
SELECT column,...
[FROM table WHERE definition]
[ORDER BY col_name [ASC | DESC], ...]
[LIMIT [offset], rows]
```

Естественно ваши запросы не будут выполняться, так как вы засунули LIMIT внутрь блока ORDER BY.

В вашем случае можно попробовать следующее:

```
order by date_time desc , TIME_TO_SEC(date_time)
limit N
```

где N - количество неких ваших записей за этот день. Но вариант прямо скажем не самый оптимальный

**UPD (появился текст запроса)**  Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то пробуйте так:
Вычленяем из date_ time день и показываем записи лишь за последний день (тут нам пригодится MAX) ну а далее сортируем по исходному date_time

```
  SELECT 
    purpose,
    date_time,
    objection,
    company_id,
    quest_id 
  FROM 
    call 
  WHERE 
    quest_id ='".$set_of_call['quest_id']."' and
    company_id='".$set_of_call['company_id']."' and
    dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, date_time), date_time) = 
      ( SELECT 
          dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, MAX(date_time)), MAX(date_time) 
        FROM
          call )
  ORDER BY date_time
```

Если же dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, date_time), date_time) У вас не сработает как надо, то воспользуйтесь любым другим преобразованием DateTime -> Date (отсеките время от даты)

Comment: Только сейчас понял... мне ведь не надо сортировать, и я так беру последнюю запись по времени...)))
У меня несколько значений $set_of_call['quest_id'] и $set_of_call['company_id']. Я их помещу в матрицу и её уже отсортирую! но все равно спасибо за старание!

Comment: Если кому-то понадобиться, то вот сортировка по дате:
Загоняем все строки в массив и :

`function sorta($a, $b) {
            if ($a['date_time'] > $b['date_time'])
                return 1;
        }
        
        usort($array, 'sorta');`

Comment: PHP весьма рекомендует, чтоб функция сортировки была полной (для корректной работы в разных будущих версиях):

    function sorta($a, $b) { 
     if ($a['date_time'] < $b['date_time']) 
  return -1; 
       else
       if ($a['date_time'] > $b['date_time']) 
  return 1;
        else
         return 0;
    }